# Add vlookup multiplier to pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

Starting from a table like:

```
Stock   Action  Shares
AAPL    BUY 100
AAPL    BUY 200
MSFT    BUY 100
MSFT    BUY 200
MSFT    SELL    -100
```

and:

```
Stock   Price
AAPL    105.5
MSFT    221.2
```

I'd like to get a table like:

```
Stock   Shares  Price   Value
AAPL    300 105.5    $31,650 
MSFT    200 221.2    $44,240
```

Just a basic portfolio value report.

[something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctulr.png)

Pivot table is great at aggregating the shares, but I can't find a way to add the value calculation.  I set up a data model and linked symbol on the two tables, then, if I start with the price table I can put the total shares next to it but when I put the price in, I can only choose sum of price ->

[Looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11VZC.png)

It feels like I'm close.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I got a solution, its maybe way harder than it needs to be but here it goes.

- Bring the tables into power pivot and create the connection on symbol
- In powerpivot

  - Add a 'CurrShares' column to the price table, set the formula to
    =[Sum of Shares]
  - Add another new column, set formula to =[Price]*[CurrShares]
- Back in the spreadsheet go to data->existing connections, select Tables tab, pick the table and import as a table

[Ends up like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNtkO.png)

thanks for help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25510224/how-do-you-copy-the-powerpivot-data-into-the-excel-workbook-as-a-table)